# Conditions for Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$, and $Y_n := X_{m-n}$, $m\ge n$.

Under what conditions is $\{Y_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ Markov chain?

I stared by proving that conditional probability of $Y_{n+1} = y$ depends only on $m, n, y$ and $Y_n$, but I wasn't able to obtain any additional conditions. What else should I consider?

Comment: *Stationary* Markov chain?

Comment: The condition for stationary Markov chain to be time-reversible is $$\pi(j)p(j,k) = \pi(k)p(k,j)$$ right? What happens when a process is not stationary?

Comment: Why are you suddenly mentioning reversibility?